# How to write a simple list-based quicksort in Idris?

Tags: idris

I'm just trying to do the bare minimum to translate the following Haskell to Idris (I'm not looking for efficiency or proofs of correctness):

```
quicksort  []           =  []
quicksort (x:xs)        =  quicksort [y | y <- xs, y<x ]
                        ++ [x]
                        ++ quicksort [y | y <- xs, y>=x]
```

Here's the Idris code I have, which is essentially unchanged from the Haskell except for needing to tell Idris that we are dealing with Ordered types:

```
quicksort: List (Ord b) -> List (Ord b)
quicksort  []           =  []
quicksort (x::xs)       =  quicksort [y | y <- xs, y<x ]
                        ++ [x]
                        ++ quicksort [y | y <- xs, y>=x]
```

However, I'm apparently doing this wrong. I see there is an answer in the question at [Quicksort in Idris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961118/quicksort-in-idris) , but the form is a bit different - I'd like to understand what is wrong with the current approach. My above code gives the error:

```
40 | quicksort (x::xs)       =  quicksort [y | y <- xs, y<x ]
   |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ...
When checking right hand side of quicksort with expected type
        List b

When checking an application of function Prelude.Applicative.guard:
        Can't find implementation for Ord (Ord b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Prelude.Applicative.guard` (function which is used for guards in list comprehensions) can't find implementation for `Ord` typeclass.

That tells us, that we haven't added (or added incorrectly) typeclass constraint. If we change your code to this one, it should work:

```
quicksort: Ord b => List b -> List  b
quicksort  []           =  []
quicksort (x::xs)       =  quicksort [y | y <- xs, y < x ]
                        ++ [x]
                        ++ quicksort [y | y <- xs, y >= x]
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense - I hadn't seen type classes in either language yet. What seems a bit surprising to me is that it is `guard` that requires an instance of the type class, and not the comparison operators; I think of guard as just saying "such that", and what follows "such that" could be something involving equality rather than inequalities.

Comment: what is `Alternative` in Idris - is it also builtin? my knowledge of Idris isn't good enough to know if my grepping was complete in trying to find its definition, but as guard uses it, I guess maybe the Ord requirement comes from there?

Comment: do you have any ideas on why `guard` requires `Ord`, or should I ask this as another question?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: `List (Ord b)` is a list of implementations for `Ord b`, while `Ord b => List b` is a list of `b` where `b` has the interface constraint of `Ord b`. Compare:

```
[ord1] Ord Nat where
   compare Z (S n)     = GT
   compare (S n) Z     = LT
   compare Z Z         = EQ
   compare (S x) (S y) = compare @{ord1} x y

imps : List (Ord b) -> List (Ord b)
imps xs = xs

ords : Ord b => List b -> List b
ords xs = xs
```

With `imps [ord1] : List (Ord Nat)` and `ords [1] : List Nat`.