# Why does guard need the Ord typeclass in Idris?

Tags: idris

In another question ([How to write a simple list-based quicksort in Idris?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224043/how-to-write-a-simple-list-based-quicksort-in-idris)), I was left trying to understand why `Prelude.Applicative.guard` requires an `Ord` typeclass.

Guard is defined [like this](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/8a34c865c2aa381356a2692d7db75b25676d011f/libs/prelude/Prelude/Applicative.idr#L47-L48):

```
guard : Alternative f => Bool -> f ()
guard a = if a then pure () else empty
```

Looking at the `Alternative` interface [docs](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Applicative.html) (I don't actually understand how it is defined in the code yet, but I'm not very far along in learning Idris), I don't see how it requires `Ord` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guard` alone does not need the `Ord` constraint, but rather `(<)` in your previous question. I gave there an answer to distingush between `List (Ord b)` and `Ord b => List b`.

To see why `guard` complains about the missing constraint, see how [monad comprehensions](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#monad-comprehensions) are de-sugared.

`[y | y <- xs, y < x]` becomes `do {y <- xs; guard (y < x); pure y}`.